# Image icons in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

I'm plotting a scatter plot of attributes of faces of people, and instead of a point marker, would like to use a little icon of the person's face as a point on the plot.  From a related thread from many years ago, it's been shown how to do this in part:

[Adding a small photo/image to a large graph in Matplotlib/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003108/adding-a-small-photo-image-to-a-large-graph-in-matplotlib-python)

However, this thread does not make mention of how to specify the icon coordinates in terms of x and y values of the plot.  Given that I have the X, Y values corresponding to the datapoints at which I want to center the icons of faces, how can I adapt this example?  Here is the accepted answer from that thread:

```
import matplotlib, scipy
fig = matplotlib.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
axicon = fig.add_axes([0.4,0.4,0.1,0.1])
ax.plot(range(5), [4,2,3,5,1])
axicon.imshow(scipy.randn(100,100))
axicon.set_xticks([])
axicon.set_yticks([])
fig.show()
```

The line that throws me off is:

```
axicon = fig.add_axes([0.4,0.4,0.1,0.1])
```

How do I translate this to x,y values on the plot?

[image]

Comment: However [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318288/how-to-use-custom-marker-with-plot) thread does. Trick lies in the mpl transformations module.

Comment: Np. I ran into that thread not even 2 days ago. Make sure you give the guy a thumbs up.